# setting up a multi-multifiltering in a plugin, is it even possible in this particular case?

Tags: jquery

Here is the problem in a nutshell. I don't know how to make filters of same row to exclude each other. For example, if you select islands, and then select cities, islands should be "deselected".

But in my case, they stack up.

This is my MixItUp setup

```
            targetSelector : '.mix',
            filterSelector : '.filter',
            sortSelector : '.sort',
            buttonEvent: 'click',
            effects : ['fade', 'scale'],
            listEffects : null,
            easing : 'smooth',
            layoutMode: 'grid',
            targetDisplayGrid : 'inline-block',
            targetDisplayList: 'block',
            listClass : '',
            gridClass : '',
            transitionSpeed : 600,
            showOnLoad : 'all',
            sortOnLoad : false,
            multiFilter : true,
            filterLogic : 'and',
            resizeContainer : true,
            minHeight : 0,
            failClass : 'fail',
            perspectiveDistance : '3000',
            perspectiveOrigin : '50% 50%',
            animateGridList : true,
            onMixLoad: null,
            onMixStart : null,
            onMixEnd : null,
```

I know it's dumb to ask of you to debug a distant site but here is application of my problem:

fiddle containing the essence of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DwX29/
Here, I want to click lemons, then small and result should be small lemons, not small lemons and small oranges. But if I click on oranges while lemons are active, lemons should be deselected and only show oranges as a result.

github: https://github.com/goxytesla/Monsi_apartments

the site: http://abbaenterijer.com/

Thanks you for taking your time to look into my problem in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I did this by creating my own click function and having a variable for each group of filters, then joining them together and running

```
$('#grid').mixitup('filter',allselectedfilters);
```

So you have a variable for fruits that contains the active filter in, as well as a variable for size that has the active size selected in.

```
var fruits = 'orange';
var size = 'small';
```

The you join the two together

```
var allselectedfilters = fruits+' '+size;
```

and run that

```
$('#grid').mixitup('filter',allselectedfilters);
```

This is a pretty simplified version but hopefully it gets you off to the right start.
Just remember that when "All" is selected then the corresponding variable should be empty but defined.